# All n-partitions of elements from a given pool

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, list, partitioning

I'm trying to write a C# algorithm that give the list of possible n-partitions from a pool containing x elements.

In order to be more clear, let's say that I have a pool of 6 elements: 1,2,3,4,5,6 (x = 6)
and I should give all partitions of 3 numbers, ie:

```
1,2,3 and 4,5,6
1,3,4 and 2,5,6
1,2,5 and 3,4,6
1,2,6 and 3,4,5
etc.
```

The function I'm targeting looks like :

```
List<List<List<int>>> GetAllPartitions(int x, int n)
```

EDIT:

What I'm looking for is not combinations... For it, I use this (taken from this site):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
{
    return k == 0
       ? new[] {new T[0]}
       : elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
             elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] {e}).Concat(c)));
}
```

Comment: Well it's not the same thing. 
What you are giving is combinaisons which I looked for and found an extension method for it.
What I'm looking for is partitions, that's why I specified that my return value is a List<List<List>>>.
I'll update my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I don't do link only answers (and generally SO likes you to show attempts at a solution too), but there is a complete code solution for objects of any type (not just int) already written in c# found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/updownroundnround/archive/2009/12/18/generating-all-partitions-of-a-set-c-implementation.aspx

Note: this will generate all partitions of every length for the set, so you will need to do a simple select on the resulting list to filter it for only your desired "n" length partitions, which can be simply:

```
var result = from allResults select result where result.length = n || result.length = x-n
```

For those worried about link death, here is the linked code:

```
/// <summary>
/// A enumeration of all possible partitions of a set of items.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the items in the set being partitioned.</typeparam>
public sealed class AllPartitionsEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>>
{
    /// <summary></summary>
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Collapsed)]
    private IEnumerable<T> items;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes an instance of the <see cref="AllPartitionsEnumerable{T}"/> type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">The set of items to be partitioned.</param>
    public AllPartitionsEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> items)
        : base ()
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an enumerator to iterate over the partitions in this enumeration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An instance of <see cref="IEnumerator{T}"/>.</returns>
    public IEnumerator<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new AllPartitionsEnumerator<T>(this.items);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an enumerator to iterate over the partitions in this enumeration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An instance of <see cref="IEnumerator{T}"/>.</returns>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
 /// <summary>
/// An enumerator to iterate over the items in an instance of <see cref="AllPartitionsEnumerable{T}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the items in the set being partitioned.</typeparam>
public sealed class AllPartitionsEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>>
{
    /// <summary>The original set of items over which partitions are created.</summary>
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private T[] items;

    /// <summary>Flag to indicate if this enumerator has been disposed of.</summary>
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private bool isDisposed;

    /// <summary>Flag to indicate if this enumerator is in its initial state.</summary>
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private bool isFirst;

    /// <summary>The number of partitions in the current selection.</summary>
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private int nc;

    /// <summary>An array of values indicating the number of values in the partition at the specified index.</summary>
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private int[] p;

    /// <summary>An array of indices indicating to which partition the item at the specified index belongs.</summary>
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private int[] q;

    /// <summary>The current partition.</summary>
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private T[][] current;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes an instance of the <see cref="AllPartitionsEnumerator{T}"/> type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">The original set of items over which partitions are enumerated.</param>
    public AllPartitionsEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> items)
        : base()
    {
        if (null == items)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
        }

        this.isFirst = true;
        this.items = items.ToArray();
        this.nc = 0;
        this.p = new int[this.items.Length];
        this.q = new int[this.items.Length];
        this.current = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current partition.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Current
    {
        get
        {
            this.CheckIfDisposed();

            return this.current;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes of this enumerator and releases all resources held by it.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.isDisposed = true;
        this.items = null;
        this.p = null;
        this.q = null;
        this.nc = 0;
        this.current = null;
        this.isFirst = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current partition.
    /// </summary>
    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Current;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Selects the next item in the set of all partitions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if an item was selected; <c>false</c> if we are past the last element.</returns>
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        this.CheckIfDisposed();

        if (this.isFirst)
        {
            this.isFirst = false;
            this.nc = 1;
            this.p[0] = this.items.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.items.Length; ++i)
            {
                this.q[i] = this.nc;
            }
            this.Select();
            return true;
        }

        if (this.nc == this.items.Length )
        {
            return false;
        }

        int n = this.items.Length;
        int m = n;
        int l = this.q[m-1];

        while (this.p[l - 1] == 1)
        {
            this.q[m - 1] = 1;
            --m;
            l = this.q[m - 1];
        }

        this.nc += m - n;
        this.p[0] = this.p[0] + n - m;

        if (l == this.nc)
        {
            ++this.nc;
            this.p[this.nc - 1] = 0;
        }

        this.q[m - 1] = l + 1;
        this.p[l - 1] = this.p[l - 1] - 1;
        this.p[l] = this.p[l] + 1;

        this.Select();
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets this enumerator to its initial state.
    /// </summary>
    public void Reset()
    {
        this.CheckIfDisposed();

        this.current = null;
        this.isFirst = true;
        this.isDisposed = false;
        this.p = new int[this.items.Length];
        this.q = new int[this.items.Length];
        this.nc = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Selects the items for the current partition.
    /// </summary>
    private void Select()
    {
        this.current = new T[this.nc][];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.nc; ++i)
        {
            int k = 0;
            this.current[i] = new T[this.p[i]];

            for (int j = 0; j < this.items.Length; ++j)
            {
                if (this.q[j] == i + 1)
                {
                    this.current[i][k] = this.items[j];
                    ++k;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks and throws an exception if this enumerator has been disposed.
    /// </summary>
    private void CheckIfDisposed()
    {
        if (this.isDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
}
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves all possible partitions of a set of items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the items in the original set.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="items">The original set of items over which partitions are created.</param>
    /// <returns>All possible partitions of the items in <paramref name="items"/>.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>> AllPartitions<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return new AllPartitionsEnumerable<T>(items);
    }
```

Comment: @L.B, thanks, I edited to clarify (I actually hit post accidentally)

Comment: "Generally I don't do link only answers" - why does this case justify making an exception? It's still basically just a link, it can still stop working, and it still points users away from [so], as opposed to providing the answer here.

Comment: Because at the time the question was of quite poor quality (has been edited significantly now) and the length of solution quite long, not to mention it is an msdn hosted site and has been up for more than 5 years. All these combined (but mainly first point) tipped the scales. Although the time spent in this reply probably could've done it by now.